# Certificate signing request for a docker containerized webserver

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate

Hopefully a quick answer.

When generating a CSR for SSL certs from a CA, do the openssl commands to create the CSR need to be run on the host where docker is installed, or in the docker container that will be the webserver?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so long as the signed certificate and the private key file wind up in the container where you expect, and you handle the private key file securely, it doesn't matter where you run the commands.

I would tend to run them on the host and inject them with a `docker run -v` option (or equivalent).  You can't add them to the image, since that leaks the private key into the immutable, shared image.  As a general rule running commands interactively inside a Docker container isn't a preferred path.  You also don't want to regenerate the certificate whenever you restart the container (and deleting a Docker container is a very routine occurrence; you need to do it to upgrade the software in the container, for instance).

Comment: Thank you @David Maze, I appreciate it